# Javascript for loop find array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a list of objects in `awards` `console.log(awards)` looks like this..

```
[0]
[1]
count
next
previous
route
getRestangularUrl
getRequestedUrl
addRestangularMethod
clone
reqParams 
etc...
```

I want to loop each array of objects ignoring all the other stuff i.e just `[0]` and `[1]`. Now I can do this when I know how many objects there are however I could have 1 or 100s.

```
 for (var key in awards) {
    if (awards[0]){


         }
     if (awards[1]){


         }

 }
```

Is there a what in javascript to detect an array in the for look?

Comment: Are you asking how to tell if a variable contains a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var index=0;

    for (var value in awards) 
    {

        if (value instanceof Array) {
            alert('value is Array!');
         } else {
              alert('Not an array');
          }

         index=index+1;

     }
```

Comment: can I get the array number form this i.e. 0, or 1

Comment: Use 'for(i=0;i<length; i++)' instead for optimized loop, rather than using both 'for in' and 'index' counter.

Answer (score 1):

This should work !

```
var array = [1,2,3, [2,3], 4 , 5, [4,5]];

for (i in array){
  if (array[i] instanceof Array === false){
    console.log(array[i]);
  }
}
```

Have a nice develop day !

Answer (score 1):

```
var i, length=awards.length;
for(i=0;i<length; i++){
    if(awards[i] instanceof Array){
        console.log("Array present at index " + i);
        console.log(awards[i]);
    }
}
```

Hope this is what you want. Let me know if this works for you.